# Intersecting Family of subsets of size k

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose that $k$ divides $n$. Then an intersecting family $F$ of $k$-subsets of an $n$-set $X$ has size at most $n-1\choose k-1$.

The prove goes as follows:

Let $B$ be the set of all partitions of n-set with each of size $k$. Let $A$ be a $k$ set where $A\in B$. By symmetry, we know each $k$ set lies in the same number of members of $B$, say $x$.

But why is that? Since $B$ is a partition, then all of the elements are grouped into non-empty disjoint subsets hence they can't all contain the element $x$.

Comment: Can you define what an intersecting family is? Also, can you say anything about the proof that you read and why it is not intuitive?

Comment: @Aravind: An intersecting family is simply a family of sets in which no two are disjoint.

Comment: Did the proof actually use the hypothesis that $k\mid n$? Because it’s true without that hypothesis: it’s the Erdős-Ko-Rado theorem, with a short probabilistic proof due to Katona.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The proof partitioned the set so it went like. let C be the set of all partitions of an n-set into n = k sets of size k , where k divides n. Then it double counted pairs.

Comment: @Luffy, note that B is a set of sets where each set is a partition .